# iphone / ipad Enterprise application Distribution

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, provisioning

i have enterprise application distribution certificate to distribute application to certain employees in an organization.

Here how to delete a particular device id in that distribution certificate.

for example consider a person is run away from the organization with device means here how'll you restrict user to access the application in that particular device.

ANy idea...

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a startup check where the app will contact a server which holds a blacklist of UDIDs of devices known to be AWOL. The app would ask the server for permission to run upon startup by transmitting the UDID of its host device.

This will of course force your devices to be online (or otherwise able to contact the server) in order to run. If this is not possible under all circumstances, the permission to run could be valid for some time. For example, the app would start up for three days after the permission was last granted before requiring a new permit.